# Updating the transcript log file modification time without adding to it

Tags: powershell

I have a log that is being started with `Start-Transcript -path "$logdir\$logname" -Append` and it does what I want in that it creates or updates the log with info on what it is doing. I have it running in a loop to check for things and send an alert if something isn't updated on time. The problem is that I want to be able to look at its log and know that it is running but I don't want a log filled with things I don't care about.

My first thought was to just update the modification date on the log file.
I tried `(Get-Item "$logdir\$logname").LastWriteTime=(Get-Date)` but that gives me the error `Exception setting "LastWriteTime": "The process cannot access the file '[the log path]' because it is being used by another process."`

Then I tried writing null characters and backspace characters, but no luck. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

I could have it just update the contents of a separate log file, but I want to reuse this many times and in many places and would prefer to avoid the clutter.

Comment: In your monitoring code, you could infer from the inability to open the transcript file for writing that the file hasn't been closed and that the process writing to it is therefore still alive. For monitoring whether actual _content_ is being added, something like `Get-Content -Wait` may help.

Comment: I think what I'm going to have it do is update a file with a different extension, deleting and then recreating a .pid version with the process ID in it.